# Is there a way to see your match history in Scrolls?

Tags: scrolls

I just played my first ranked match but after leaving it:

- is there a way to check the game stats again? Better yet it would be nice to access a replay feature...
- is there at least a way to keep in touch with the guy I just played against? Say if I want to play against him/her again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there isn't.  However, according to [this Scrolls Guide blog post](http://www.scrollsguide.com/news/1560/scrolls-modloader-spoiler), a mod is in the works that will allow for deck importation and will also display a list of previous matches.  Few details have been posted regarding the match history.

The image below is currently all the information we have regarding this coming update.

[image]

**UPDATE**

Summoner, the unofficial mod-loader from Scrolls Guide is out.  ([Get it here.](http://www.scrollsguide.com/summoner))  This mod provides a way for you to both see a list of your previous matches and watch a virtual-replay.  Summoner is available for both Windows and OS X.